# Autocomplete for SAPUI5 in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, sapui5

I installed SAP Hana Toolkit for Eclipse Luna. But autocomplete doesn't work.

I completed steps in the link below. It doesn't work.

https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/85/ce1edb55dd4de3beac5b6d24d36d8a/content.htm

I tried to follow the steps in the link below. But I've stuck at step 3. There isn't a "Sap Component Library for JSF" selection.

http://www.ameyablog.com/sapui5/how-to-enable-code-completion-feature-for-sapui5-projects

Comment: Can you please explain the reason of negative vote? I don't want to do that mistake in the future.

Comment: I don´t see a reason for down votes, too. I didn´t do step 3 and it´s working well. Did you complete all the other steps properly? How do you create the project. Are you using the SAPUI5 Application Project Wizard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The autocomplete seems to be mostly broken at the moment. Can you try this please:

In your eclipse editor, open a JS view and write something like `var button = new Button`. After `Button` you press ctrl & space. You should get a collection of possible `sap.` objects to be autocompleted.

Does this work? It is not full autocompletion yet (e.g. it *mostly* does not work on functions for object variables), but a good test to check if your setup is correct.

I got *more* (read: not full) autocompletion after updating my SAPUI5 plug ins.

Comment: After the update it's started working. As you said it's not complete, but it's  something. Thanks for the heads up.